# Confusion on wording of question for row space and null space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have what seems to be a fairly simple question.

> Write the row space and the null space of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\\ \end{bmatrix}$$as a span of vectors.

I feel like this is a very simple question.   Is this not just the same as finding the basis for the row space and null space?

So after row reduction, I get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\\ \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Is the basis of the row space not just then $\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,2)\}$ and the null space $\{(1,-2,1) \}$? A basis is a linearly independent spanning set so is the answer not just as simple as this? I feel like I am missing something very obvious...

Comment: You are correct...(assuming your calculations are correct). Why do you think you're missing something?

Comment: Because it said write as the span of vectors and I wasn't sure if the basis I wrote meant the exact same thing. I think I overthought the question.

Comment: Technically, you are expected to write $\text{row space} = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,2)\}$ and analogously for the column space.